# heroku db:push showing invalid database url

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to push data to a heroku app by using

`heroku db:push`

but it is spitting out this error:

```
root@ubuntu-lappy:~/rails/soft$ heroku db:push 
Invalid database url
```

any clue regarding this? my taps installation went fine because I was able to push the DB out before.

Is there something in particular I should be looking at?

EDIT:
If you are looking for answer to this problem then you are better off providing the freaking URL yourself.  Answered in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168443/how-to-connect-to-postgresql-using-url)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

yes, make sure you are in the project root, I just ran into this problem as well

Answer (score 4):

You need to have a database.yml file in your config directory so it knows what database to push from.

Comment: The database to pull into, rather, but yes, this was the solution for my case :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to specify the db name, login and password using that format: heroku db:push postgres://username:password@localhost/myrailsdb

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the `/db` directory rather than at the root of your Rails app, you can get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
heroku info
```

If you get anything other than something like this (assuming the app name is 'blah-blah-app-name-9897'):

```
=== blah-blah-app-name-9897
Addons:        PG Backups Basic, Shared Database 5MB
Database Size: 184k
Domain Name:   blah-blah-app-name-9897.herokuapp.com
Git URL:       git@heroku.com:blah-blah-app-name-9897.git
Owner:         owner_email@jmail.com
Repo Size:     9M
Slug Size:     30M
Stack:         cedar
Web URL:       http://blah-blah-app-name-9897.herokuapp.com/
```

Then something is wrong with your heroku setup.

Post the output of your heroku info here to see details.