# How to connect to postgresql using url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, taps

I had asked an earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144603/heroku-dbpush-showing-invalid-database-url) which did not get any replies.

Basically I get an error `invalid database url` when I try to do `heroku db:push`.

I figured I can try explicitly providing the database url.

I tried:

`heroku db:push postgres://postgres@localhost/myrailsdb`

But that gave error:

```
Failed to connect to database:
  Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError -> PGError fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

What is the format for providing username and password?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Try `heroku db:push postgres://username:password@localhost/myrailsdb`.

Comment: what if your local db user has no password?

Comment: Just drop the password, i.e. `db push postgres://username@localhost/myrailsdb`

Comment: If no password is supplied, this will give an error of

Failed to connect to database:
  Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError -> PGError fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Comment: You can also add query parameters at the end to specify additional attributes - e.g. `?pool=5`. For Ruby on Rails specifically any attributes specified in `DATABASE_URL` will override attributes specified in `config/database.yml`. See: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database

Answer (score 17):

according to documentation

```
postgresql://[user[:password]@][netloc][:port][/dbname][?param1=value1&...]
```

examples

```
postgresql://
postgresql://localhost
postgresql://localhost:5432
postgresql://localhost/mydb
postgresql://user@localhost
postgresql://user:secret@localhost
postgresql://other@localhost/otherdb?connect_timeout=10&application_name=myapp
postgresql://localhost/mydb?user=other&password=secret
```

Comment: "postgresql://localhost/mydb?user=other&password=secret" does not seem to use the specified password. Only "postgresql://user:secret@localhost" works.

Answer (score 14):

Here's how to do it in a Ruby script:

```
# Connect to database.
uri = URI.parse(ENV['DATABASE_URL'])
postgres = PG.connect(uri.hostname, uri.port, nil, nil, uri.path[1..-1], uri.user, uri.password)

# List all tables.
tables = postgres.exec('SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables')
tables.num_tuples.times do |i|
  p tables[i]
end
```

Comment: What are your imports/requires?

Answer (score 5):

Edit your postgresql configuration (pg_hba.conf) file and change 'host' type method to 'trust'. But be aware that this is not secure.

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Restart your postgresql server and re-run the command

```
$ heroku db:push postgres://postgres@localhost/myrailsdb
```

Here is the reference to my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7667344/181677

Comment: where is the pg_hba.conf file located?

Comment: actually, found it. for ubuntu, Debian/Ubuntu: /etc/postgresql/9.0/main/pg_hba.conf

Comment: what to do if I have the error about pg_hba.conf on remote server (heroku)? I can't change anything there and changing local file does not make any difference, ofc

Answer (score 1):

Heroku cli has changed the command.

```
heroku pg:push postgres://username:password@localhost/myrailsdb
```