# PostgreSQL authentification with password

Tags: database, linux, postgresql, authentication

I work with PostgreSQL 9.2 and have command:

```
psql -h localhost -U testdb -d postgis
```

This command has the ability to connect database without password. I want to enter a password.

My `pg_hba.cconf` is:

```
local   all             all                                     password
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Comment: have you restarted the server after you changed config file?

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko: [A reload should suffice.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667193/heroku-dbpull-failing-due-to-lack-of-password-when-i-havent-specified-a-passwo/7667344#7667344)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Password-less access requires that one of several [authentication methods](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/client-authentication.html) is configured accordingly. More details in these related answers:
[pgadmin gives me the error: no password supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035742/pgadmin-gives-me-the-error-no-password-supplied/14042436#14042436)
[Run batch file with psql command without password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359348/run-batch-file-with-psql-command-without-password/15593100#15593100)

In particular, `localhost` is not a "local connection" in the `pg_hba.conf` file in the second one. Since you are connecting with `-h localhost`, only the lines starting with `host` in your `pg_hba.conf` file are applicable, so a password should be required.

Remaining explanations:

- [You did not `reload`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667193/heroku-dbpull-failing-due-to-lack-of-password-when-i-havent-specified-a-passwo/7667344#7667344) since the config file was changed.
- You are not showing the right (or complete) `pg_hba.conf` (or inadvertently connecting to the wrong db cluster. Port 5432?) and there is in fact a line with `peer` or `ident` authentication that comes before other `host` lines.
- Your installation has a [`.pgpass` file](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/libpq-pgpass.html) in place, that grants access to the system user you are running the command with. For details, refer to [the second linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359348/run-batch-file-with-psql-command-without-password/15593100#15593100).

The last one seems most likely.